# variable not getting set by jquery code

Tags: jquery

have these simple lines where I have a textarea with id txtArea which I allow the user to fill     with text after fading it in since it was initialized with style = diplay:none

```
  var area = $('#txtArea');
  str = area.val();
  document.write("here i am" + str);
```

When this prints I just get "here I am"   Why isn't the variable capturing the input?

The html for the div that contains txtArea is

```
</div>
<div id="newtext" style="display:none" >
<textarea rows="50" cols="200" id = "txtArea"  > </textarea>
<button class="btn2">SEE YOUR TEXT</button>

</div>
```

Comment: where's the html with `id="txtArea"`?

Comment: then put the html in the question.

Comment: </div>
<div id="newtext" style="display:none" >
</div>
<div id="newtext" style="display:none" >
<textarea rows="50" cols="200" id = "txtArea"  > </textarea>
<button class="btn2">SEE YOUR TEXT</button>

</div>

Answer (score 1):

I think This may help u
in your code i don't know why u had style="display:none". it will not show any thing inside the div. so i remove it in my code.

For Live DEMO [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jDFwk/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="newtext"  >
<textarea  id = "txtArea"  > </textarea>
<button class="btn2" id="btn">SEE YOUR TEXT</button>
</div>
<div id="yourtext">
</div>
```

JQ

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#btn").click(function () {
$("#yourtext").text("here i am "+$("#txtArea").val());
});

 });
```

For Live DEMO [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jDFwk/1/)
 If this is what you need put a **Reply..**